# Switching from side by side Ubuntu to main OS on Lenovo laptop

Tags: installation, virtualbox, password, root

I am loving Ubuntu and I would like to switch from Ubuntu 12.10 side by side with Win7 to Ubuntu as the sole OS (and eventually run Win7 via virtualbox).  After I backup everything, wipe the entire SSD and re-install Ubuntu as the sole OS, how do I keep my previous Linux identity?

*Examples*:

- **Username**
- Computer name
- **Root** password

Thanks...

P.S. If you have seen this question before, could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean by "wipe the SSD"? Do you need secure deletion?

Comment: Basically removing everything from the SSD and starting a new installation. Or does Ubuntu does that for me?  Curious about your question.  Be well...

Comment: Then you do not need to delete or "wipe", since you're going to repartition anyway; the files are lost as soon as the installer creates the new partition over the old one. No reason to worry about TRIM/discard, because mkfs.ext4 discards the blocks as the first thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My low tech method is to memorize those 3 things and just type them in on a new installation. Or write them on a piece of paper and destroy the paper after the new system is up and running.

Comment: It's also my _high tech_ method. This is the simplest and less error-prone way.

Comment: Thank you asp and ignis, I asked that question because I did not know if once you created an identity with a Linux distribution that identity followed you forever (i.e. your Facebook account, if you have it, is the same regardless of the electronic device you are using). After all, GNU/Linux is what we all commonly use, and if we are going to communicate to other Linux users (call it Ubuntu, Fedora, Arch, etc) don't we have to have a unique identifier? Another example is that in gmail you cannot have two /*john.doe@gmail.com*/  I hope I make any sense.  Live long and prosper.

Comment: The unique identifier is local to the machine, internally it is a number, and most machines assign the same number(s) to their users. For example, the user created by the Ubuntu installer typically has user ID 1000. It's the third field in the `/etc/passwd` file (user ID).

Comment: Great, thanks! I have a lot to learn, but excited about it. I want to learn more about Linux itself. Discovered [link](www.Linuxacademy.com) today. Have you guys used it?

Comment: Never heard of it, and will never use it. I believe Arch Linux and Gentoo are way cheaper and more effective in teaching Linux internals. If you want to ask for websites, please open a new question

Comment: I am back guys.  Thank you all who replied.  Still on Linux and as main OS shortly after my question.

Comment: Linuxacademy.com gives you structure (in my opinion). I installed Arch in Virtualbox with a YouTube tutorial. I find that the Arch wiki doesn't work for me. I am also getting ready to leave Ubuntu. Candidates: SolydX and Antergos.